# I want to parse div using BeautifulSoup from a website but it returns empty list

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract data from [AIESEC.org](https://aiesec.org/) like opportunities available and what it provides.

I tried :

```py
import requests
import bs4


Explorer = requests.get('https://aiesec.org/search')


def explore(Explorer):
    src = Explorer.content
    soup = (bs4.BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml'))
    container = soup.findAll('div',  {'class': 'container-body'})
    print(container)


explore(Explorer)
```

The output :

```
#Empty List
[]
```

I want it to return the HTML code, scrape it, and use this data in a spreadsheet.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You can't. Data are loaded from a javascript application. You have to use selenium to browse the content.

Comment: @Corralien Can we crawl data with api? I tried that but status code is 404. Can we avoid that?

Comment: @Corralien for ex. this [api](https://gis-api.aiesec.org/graphql)

Comment: It will be a pain to try to explore the data with graphql. Really, you should use Selenium

Comment: @Elkhan you'd need to know the parameters or payload for the API, which means reverse engineering the script(s) that call it.

Comment: Thanks . I was curious about if there is any option but selenium. I understood there is not )

Answer (score 1):

You can use their Ajax API to load the info about the programs. For example (you have to adjust the search variables though):

```py
import json
import requests

api_url = 'https://gis-api.aiesec.org/graphql'

payload = {
    "operationName": "GetAllOpportunitiesQuery",
    "query": "query GetAllOpportunitiesQuery($only: String, $page: Int, $per_page: Int, $q: String, $with: String, $sort: String, $smart_search: Boolean, $filters: OpportunityFilter, $cdn_links: Boolean, $loggedInUser: Boolean!, $gpPage: Int, $gpPerPage: Int, $gpFilters: OpportunityFilter, $rpPage: Int, $rpPerPage: Int, $rpFilters: OpportunityFilter) {\n  allOpportunity: allOpportunity(\n    only: $only\n    page: $page\n    per_page: $per_page\n    q: $q\n    with: $with\n    sort: $sort\n    smart_search: $smart_search\n    filters: $filters\n  ) {\n    data {\n      ...Opportunity\n      __typename\n    }\n    paging {\n      total_items\n      total_pages\n      current_page\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  globalPartnersOpportunities: allOpportunity(\n    only: $only\n    page: $gpPage\n    per_page: $gpPerPage\n    q: $q\n    with: $with\n    sort: $sort\n    smart_search: $smart_search\n    filters: $gpFilters\n  ) {\n    data {\n      ...Opportunity\n      __typename\n    }\n    paging {\n      total_items\n      total_pages\n      current_page\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  regionalPartnersOpportunities: allOpportunity(\n    only: $only\n    page: $rpPage\n    per_page: $rpPerPage\n    q: $q\n    with: $with\n    sort: $sort\n    smart_search: $smart_search\n    filters: $rpFilters\n  ) {\n    data {\n      ...Opportunity\n      __typename\n    }\n    paging {\n      total_items\n      total_pages\n      current_page\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment Opportunity on Opportunity {\n  applicants_count\n  applications_close_date\n  applied_to @include(if: $loggedInUser)\n  branch {\n    company {\n      id\n      name\n      profile_photo(cdn_links: $cdn_links)\n      __typename\n    }\n    id\n    __typename\n  }\n  cover_photo(cdn_links: $cdn_links)\n  description\n  host_lc {\n    id\n    address_detail {\n      id\n      country\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  id\n  partner_type\n  is_global_project\n  is_favourited @include(if: $loggedInUser)\n  duration\n  opportunity_duration_type {\n    id\n    duration_type\n    __typename\n  }\n  earliest_start_date\n  location\n  programme {\n    id\n    short_name\n    short_name_display\n    __typename\n  }\n  project_name\n  project_description\n  remote_opportunity\n  experience_type\n  specifics_info {\n    salary\n    salary_currency {\n      id\n      alphabetic_code\n      __typename\n    }\n    salary_periodicity\n    __typename\n  }\n  role_info {\n    learning_points_list\n    __typename\n  }\n  sdg_info {\n    id\n    sdg_target {\n      description\n      goal_index\n      id\n      parent {\n        id\n        name\n        short_name\n        __typename\n      }\n      target_id\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  template_opportunities_locations\n  title\n  __typename\n}\n",
    "variables": {
        "filters": {
            "earliest_start_date": {
                "from": "2023-04-05"
            }
        },
        "gpFilters": {
            "earliest_start_date": {
                "from": "2023-04-05"
            },
            "partner_type": [
                "global"
            ],
            "programmes": [
                2,
                8
            ]
        },
        "gpPage": 1,
        "gpPerPage": 3,
        "loggedInUser": False,
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 10,
        "q": "",
        "rpFilters": {
            "earliest_start_date": {
                "from": "2023-04-05"
            },
            "partner_type": [
                "regional"
            ],
            "programmes": [
                2,
                8
            ]
        },
        "rpPage": 1,
        "rpPerPage": 3,
        "smart_search": True,
        "sort": "relevance"
    }
}

headers = {'Authorization': 'e316ebe109dd84ed16734e5161a2d236d0a7e6daf499941f7c110078e3c75493'}

for payload['variables']['page'] in range(1, 4):
    data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()

    # uncomment this to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    # print some data from the response:
    for data in data['data']['allOpportunity']['data']:
        print(data['project_name'].strip())
        print(data['project_description'].strip())
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Youth 4 Impact
The project aims to impact SDG #4 by generating awareness and fostering engagement towards the sustainable development goals and global citizen values.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Green Leaders
The project aims to impact SDG #13 by educating communities about climate change and building action plans to reduce critical factors affecting the environment.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Raise Your Voice
The project aims to impact SDG #5 by fostering educational spaces that generate awareness about gender related issues and build initiatives to work on solutions to stop gender inequality in communities around the globe.

...and so on.
```

Comment: @AndrejKesely what is payload could you explain to me?

Comment: @Elkhan The *payload* is just some data the client is sending with to the server. In this case server expects a JSON data to perform a Graphql query. Server parses this Json payload and returns the data (opportunities).

Comment: @AndrejKesely How did you write it. For ex what is operationName or other stuff in the code. If you could give compherensive explanation it would be great.

Comment: @Elkhan I don't know what each of the parameter does. I copied the payload from the Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab. You can open the Web Developer Tools in Chrome/Firefox, click to Network Tab and reload the page. The API URL with the payload should be visible there.